# выбрать и отметить выбранные поля MySql циклом PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день вам! Ищу путь как реализовать следующее:
Нужно из БД на удаленном сервере взять данные, отметить поля которые попали в выборку и вставить их в БД на другом сервере.
Мои размышления привели меня к следующему :
Добавил столбец в БД из которой беру данные `IsUpdated` = 0, в цикле беру по 300 `SELECT` помещаю в массив, `UPDATE` таблицы из которой брал данные `IsUpdated` = 1, и `INSERT` в конечную таблицу.
Не получается прогнать цикл до тех пор, пока все нужные строки не будут иметь в поле `IsUpdated` цифру 1.
Итог кода - 743 записи в БД вместо 62 с небольшим тысяч, а вторая таблица полностью обновилась `IsUpdated` вместо 0 стало 1. Не понимаю что не так.
Нет сообщений об ошибках, связанных с тайм-аутом.

```
do{

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('h.o.s.t', 'login', 'pass', 'db_1');
mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Ошибка подключения (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
    . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT
    row1, row2, row3
      FROM
        `db_1`.`tabe_1`
    WHERE
        Result <='3'            AND
        State = 'disabled'   AND
        IsUpdated = 0
    ORDER BY
        abc DESC
    LIMIT
        300";
if(!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
die('Ошибка выполнения запроса (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($row1, $row2, $row3);
$sql = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$row1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($row1);
$row2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($row2);
$row3 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($row3);
$sql[] = "('$row1', '$row2', '$row3')";
}
$mysqliUpdate = "UPDATE `db_1`.`tabe_1` SET `IsUpdated` = 1
      WHERE
        Result <='3'            AND
        State = 'disabled'   AND
        `IsUpdated` = 0
        ORDER BY
        abc DESC
      LIMIT 300";
$mysqli->query($mysqliUpdate);
$mysqli->close();

$mysqli1 = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'example');
mysqli_query($mysqli1, 'SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
if ($mysqli1->connect_error) {
die('Ошибка подключения (' . $mysqli1->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli1->connect_error);
}

if(count($sql) > 0) {
  $query1 = "INSERT INTO `db_2`.`table_2` VALUES "
       . implode(',', $sql) .
       " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
           row1              = VALUES(row1),
           row1              = VALUES(row2),
           row1              = VALUES(row3)";
$mysqli1->query($query1);
$mysqli1->close();
}
}while (count($sql) > 0);
```

Comment: я думаю у вас скрипт по таймауту отваливается или по памяти.

Comment: @Naumov на удаленном сервере все обновляется, локалхост тоже не говорит об ошибках и не зависает.

Comment: В логах сервера тоже пусто?

Comment: @Naumov в логи сервера залезть не могу. Еще попробовал сделать sleep() перед повторным заходом на цикл - не помогло.

Comment: А вы апдейтите не те 300 записей, которые выбирали. Вы выбираете с ORDER BY, а UPDATE даете без сортировки ... И вообще подход кривоват, между select и update может пройти какое то изменение в БД и update поменяет не те записи что были выбраны даже при правильной сортировке

Comment: сделай какой нибудь вывод в конце `while ` к примеру `echo 'test'` что бы посмотреть сколько интераций цыкла прошло. p.s. почему нет доступа к логам?

Comment: В общем я бы предложил сначала IsUpdated менять на некое уникальное число (которое например запоминать в другой таблице и каждый раз увеличивать), так сказать "номер выгрузки". после чего выбирать и переносить в другую БД записи именно с этим числом.

Comment: @Mike данные из БД стягиваются ночью кроном, когда БД отдыхает.
Количество итераций цикла - 88. Получается 88*300=26400 (в базе 26377)
Странность которую не могу понять  - все нужные строки поля IsUpdated обновились, а вот INSERT не прошел полностью. Всего INSERT 1200 строк.

Comment: @Mike, Naumov  спасибо за советы!
Вариант с "номером выгрузки" у меня не получился. Номера проставились в БД где брал инфо, но вставить все не удалось.
Решил вопрос кроном. Поставил SELECT лимит на 1000 записей.